# Integration CKEditor 4 with Rails 6 via webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker

I have to upgrade a legacy application that uses CKEdtior for the text editor features.

Since the Ruby gem for ckeditor is not so good maintained anymore and Rails 6 seems to be an issue anyway I decided to go straight with webpacker.
I added ckeditor v 4 with a `yarn add` command and then I am importing the js files in my application.js/active_admin.js files. (`import "ckeditor4";`)
According to documentation I have to set a `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` constant as well. The constant should point to the path where the ckeditor files are located.
To have this files I have configured webpacker with this additional setting: `environment.config.set('output.libraryTarget', 'umd')`

I thought that this would create a ckeditor directory in my public/packs/js folder but it's not working. How can I make webpack create this folded/files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with adding the CopyPlugin and configuring it like this:

```
environment.plugins.append('CopyPlugin',
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            {
                from: '{config.js,contents.css,styles.js,adapters/**/*,lang/**/*,plugins/**/*,skins/**/*,vendor/**/*}',
                to: resolvePath( distPath, 'js/ckeditor' ),
                context: resolvePath( __dirname, '../../node_modules', 'ckeditor4' )
            }
        ]
    })
)
```